# How to use viewPager2 wrap content or change hight size item?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

How to use viewPager2 wrap content or change hight item?

**I've tried so far:**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
```

**I got error :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pages must fill the whole ViewPager2 (use match_parent)
```

if i use :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

it works. But, item is very big